# Qt 5 - How to send data back from child dialog in real time

Tags: c++, qt, modal-dialog, parent-child

I have a settings dialog that has some settings that require another dialog to fully configure. My window shows a preview of the data as it's being tweaked by these settings. Upon clicking on the configuration button I launch another modal dialog with some knobs to twist to fine tune the particular setting.

I wish to send the result of the twisting of the knobs on the child dialog back to the parent dialog so that it can show the new preview data as the knobs on the child are being played with. The way I imagine it is I have a "refresh preview" function in the parent that is called after modification of it's data preview member variables. The question is, how do I do this? How can I access getters/setters from the parent dialog as a modal child dialog? If I do access them will the preview change or will it be blocked because of the modality of the child?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qt world, it is generally encouraged to exploit the Signal/Slot mechanism. In short, classes can send signals when something changes within that class. And slots can receive such signals provided we notified the receiving classes appropriately.

Let us look at how we can do it for our present case.

In our settings dialog constructor, we include this code (assumption is that you display the "another" dialog when a button is pressed):

```
Dialog *dialog = new Dialog();
connect(dialog->dial(), &QDial::valueChanged, this, &QSettingsDialog::changeTemp);
```

Code walkthrough:

- Our QDialog has been constructed with a QDial object, dial. We access that member pointer with dialog->dial().
- We tie the signal that emits the value changed on the dial to the slot called changeTemp that receives the value changed and sets the display widget on the settings dialog (parent) accordingly.

The changeTemp method might be like so:

```
void QSettingsDialog::changeTemp(int val)
{
    lineEdit->setText(QString::number(val));
}
```

Notes:

- You need to declare the Q_OBJECT macro on all classes that need to implement Signals and slot. In this case, both the settings dialog and the child dialog.
- The above signal/slot signature is the new Qt5 signature. If you are on a version below 5.0, the signature is different. Refer to the docs.

Comment: By settings dialog constructor I assume you mean the parent dialog?